# Weird tableViewCell issue on iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

These "pipe" characters are appearing in some of my cells on my table view, but only on iOS 6. The first screenshot shows the issue on iOS 6, and the lower screenshot is iOS 4.3:

I appreciate any help offered.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d%d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        UIView *clearColor = [[UIView alloc] init];
        clearColor.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = clearColor;
    }

    UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 243.5, 25)];
    [label1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:16.0]];
    [label1 setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    label1.text = [[self.tableDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"];
    [cell addSubview:label1];

    UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(253.5, 10, 243.5, 25)];
    [label2 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:16.0]];
    [label2 setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    label2.text = [[self.tableDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Email"];
    [cell addSubview:label2];

    UILabel *label3 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(507, 10, 243.5, 25)];
    [label3 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:16.0]];
    [label3 setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    label3.text = [[self.tableDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Phone"];
    [cell addSubview:label3];

    UILabel *label4 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(760.5, 10, 243.5, 25)];
    [label4 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:16.0]];
    [label4 setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    label4.text = [[self.tableDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Business"];
    [cell addSubview:label4];

    return cell;
}
```

<sub>click for larger image</sub>

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had to set each label's background color to clear:

```
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

Any specific reason you're using UILabels?  I checked the code for an iOS6 application I have and I used NSStrings.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  NSString *newTitle = @"my string";
  cell.textLabel.text = newTitle;
}
```

Comment: He needs to display 4 different data in each cell, that's why he used four labels. you can add a single data using `cell.textLabel.text`.

Answer (score 1):

set clear background colour for labels

label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];